# Cordova w/Crosswalk white bar bug on Android

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

When using Cordova (with Crosswalk), it seems like occasionally when my app starts up, there's a white bar at the bottom. Restarting the app often fixes it, but this creates poor user experience.

It seems to only happen on Android.

Anyone know a fix for this?